# Split string in csharp as like javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, string, split

I'm trying to import some text from html object in C# form.

```
var a = document.getElementById('js_CityPosition0Link').title;
console.log(a);

var b = a.split(" (");
console.log(b);

var c = b[0];
console.log(c);
```

I can get "a" string but I can't convert to "c" in C# language as like javascript.

Comment: Please paste the code instead of providing a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Did you try [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) in C#? Can you show us your code for that since it's unclear why that wouldn't work in the same way.

Comment: It is also expected you attempt to have a go at coding this yourself so please also show your c# effort

Comment: This looks like a job for [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @Longoon12000 Really? A simple split operation looks like a job for RegEx? Why?

Comment: Because it's simple pattern matching to extract values from a regular format.

Comment: I can split with only a char in c# . I want to split with this" (". I'm already tried but I can't.

Comment: _"can split with only a char in c#"_ - Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8). `Split` has 6 overloads, 2 of which take string delimiters.

Comment: @John Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to an array, and then you will be able to split the string

```
      string str = "Belediye Binasi (10)";
            string[] str_toArray = str.Split('(');

            foreach(string val in str_toArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The result you need : {0}", str_toArray[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Result :

```
Belediye Binasi
10)
The result you need : Belediye Binasi
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the results as text, not as an image of text. The console provides the ability to copy from it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Split or Substring or IndexOf and other string manipulation functions, you can do it in a one line Regex:

```
string a = "Belediye Binasi (10)";
string c = Regex.Match(a, @"^(.+) \(\d+\)$").Groups[1].Value;
```

It's also less error prone in other cases, for example when `a` is `Belediye (Ye Boi) Binasi (10)`.

Split is nice for when you actually want to split something in parts (like a list of properties), but when extracting data from a regular (meaning the format doesn't change) text then regex is the best way to do it.